# apache flink session support

Tags: session, streaming, apache-flink

I am investigating Apache Flink Streaming to be used in our platform for ETL and machine learning. The thing i haven't figured out yet is how to stream events into 'sessions'. More descriptive: all events do contain a session id and in order to enrich data I need to group all events belonging to a session together. Please take into account that events are continuously stream in (thus no batch support after which you could simply do a groupBy e.g.)

One possible solution could be to maintain a LRU cache of sessions and sort all incoming events to their associated session. Then after X minutes of inactivity per session one can 'close' or evict the session from the cache. The question is how to deal with this cache in a multi tenant system; does flink has the concept of a distributed cache or does it contain some sort of smart load balancer where events are directed to the same partition in the grid?

More generally: What's the best way (use cases and pitfalls) to establish session support using the streaming api? Is this possible at all? And how to deal with replaying streams? (i.e. start from a particular point-in-time where events stream in of incomplete sessions (i.e. with events before point-in-time)

Interested in any feedback, ideas and/or pointers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I created an example that could be pretty close to what you require: https://gist.github.com/aljoscha/91b6422114eac814479f

I uses a `Tuple2<Integer,String>` to simulate data. The integer is the session ID while the String is some field on which we *key* (partition) the data.

I suggest you first take a look at the `main()` method, there you see the flow of the program. The other bits are the custom window definition `SessionWindow` a window assigner and the `SessionTrigger`. This basically implements the idea of the cache that you suggested. The windows are kept in buffers based on the assigned windows and the key. Once the Trigger fires we process the window and the contents are evicted.

When the trigger receives an element it registers a timer for 10 seconds in the future. If no new element arrives by that time the trigger will fire. If a new element arrives within that time window it will register a new timer, this will replace the old timer since triggers can only have one active timer at a time.

Also, this uses what is called *processing-time windows*. This can also be changed to to the triggering based on the *event-time*, i.e. the timestamp of your elements.

Comment: Thanks @aljoscha - that example is very helpful.

Comment: I've been playing around with that example, I can't seem to get the session trigger to work for event-time based windows (although it works fine for processing-time windows). I will fork your gist - it is the same code, but the Trigger registers + processes event time, and I have extracted timestamps from the input. When run, everything ends up in the same window (with flink 1.0-SNAPSHOT) - any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have managed to get it working with event-time based windows by using EventTimeSourceFunction and collectWithTimestamp rather than assignTimestamps.

Comment: I should also work with assignTimestamps. Could you maybe post your example code where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions can be extracted from an event stream with `EventTimeSessionWindows`. It combines all events appearing one after another forming *session window* until the gap between them is bigger than the value one specified. If a stream contains many sessions (which can be identified by `sessionId` in each event) then one should group by session id first so that session windows will be held for each session separately.

In the code sample below events of the form

```
case class Event(
    createdat: Timestamp,
    session: String
)
```

are transformed to

```
case class SessionEvent(
    sessionId: String,
    start: Instant,
    end: Instant,
    `type`: String
)
```

`SessionEvent` is emitted when there has been no events for the last 20 minutes (`sessionTimeout`).

```scala
// Apache Flink 1.1.4 with Kafka connector

import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.ProcessingTimeSessionWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaConsumer09, FlinkKafkaProducer09}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

object Main extends App {

  val sessionTimeout = Time minutes 20
  val kafkaCluster = "localhost:9092"
  val inputTopic = "events"
  val outputTopic = "sessions"

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val properties = new Properties
  properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaCluster)
  properties.setProperty("group.id", "sessions")

  val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09[String](inputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema, properties)
  val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer09[String](kafkaCluster, outputTopic, new SimpleStringSchema)

  val stream =
    env
      .addSource(consumer)
      .map(Formats.readEvent _)
      .keyBy(_.session)
      .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows withGap sessionTimeout)
      .apply[SessionEvent] {
        (key: String, window: TimeWindow, values: Iterable[Event], out: Collector[SessionEvent]) ⇒
          val session =
            SessionEvent(
              key,
              values.head.createdat.toInstant,
              values.last.createdat.toInstant,
              "end"
            )
          out.collect(session)
      }
      .map(Formats.writeSessionEvent _)
      .addSink(producer)

  env.execute("sessions")
}
```

Comment: provide some description about your answer before the code